# How do I connect SceneBuilder to Netbeans 11, I am getting an error when trying to create a new Java ant JavaFX FXML Application

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

I am attempting to connect SceneBuilder to Netbeans, which appears to be completed when I check in netbeans by going to preferences then java then java fx, it says SceneBuilder is integrated. Having said that when I go to create a new Java Ant JavaFX FXML Application is displays the following error

Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform. Please go to Platform Manager, create a non-default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX tab, enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX Runtime. Note: JavaFX SDK can be downloaded from JavaFX website.

I have downloaded JavaFX 14 and it is currently on my desktop, I am not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

you can't create javafx 14 with jdk 13 directly, you need to follow this steps from javafx official website
https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: When I tried this I got "Module javafx.controls not found", do I have to download that separately?

Answer (score 0):

I see this message before
try this:
go to your project properties>Compiling>
     uncheck Compile and Save
I do this and it works